# TypeError: object of type 'datetime.timedelta' has no len()

Tags: python, datetime, web-scraping, timedelta

i´m having a problem with a code. I need to subtract a day in a datetime.now to webscrapping a workbook from the Anbima site (a brazilian financial data site). Please, someone know how can i solve this?

Code:

```py
today = datetime.now(timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')).strftime("%d/%m/%Y") 
today = timedelta(days=-1) #today = '29/11/2022'
wd.find_element(By.NAME, "Dt_Ref").clear()
wd.find_element(By.NAME, "Dt_Ref").send_keys(today)
```

and the error:

```py
today = datetime.now(timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')).strftime("%d/%m/%Y") 
today = timedelta(days=-1) #today = '29/11/2022' 
wd.find_element(By.NAME, "Dt_Ref").clear()
wd.find_element(By.NAME, "Dt_Ref").send_keys(today)
```

I tried to do the timedelta but its not working. If there is another way to subtract a day i accept please.

Comment: * the correct error is this: TypeError: object of type 'datetime.timedelta' has no len()

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```py
today = timedelta(days=-1) #today = '29/11/2022'
```

is overwriting the `today` variable. You should instead use an augmented assignment so you can subtract 1 day from `today`:

```py
today = datetime.now(timezone('America/Sao_Paulo'))
today -= timedelta(days=1)
wd.find_element(By.NAME, "Dt_Ref").clear()
wd.find_element(By.NAME, "Dt_Ref").send_keys(today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that `today` has a `str` value, not a `datetime` value, so the call to `strftime` on the previous line needs to be removed as well.

Comment: `today = datetime.now(...) - timedelta(days=1)`.